# SMTPLIB-email on Cronjob fails

Tags: python, cron, smtplib

I am trying to send an email from a cronjob via smtplib. Running the python-script as user or as root works correctly, however as a cron-job I "think" I get problems connecting to the server.
The code itself is the following:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from datetime import datetime

def send_mail(subject, mail_text, to_addr):
    FROM = "myaddress@gmail.com"
    SUBJECT = subject

    TEXT = (mail_text)

    mail_user=FROM
    mail_password="<password>"
    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)
    print("message")
    print(message)
    try:
        print("a")
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
        print(server)
        print("b")
        print(server.ehlo())
        print("Login on Server")
        print(server.login(mail_user, mail_password))
        print("Sending Mail")
        print(server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message))
        print("Closing Connection")
        server.close()
        print('Successfully sent the mail')
    except Exception as e:
        print( "failed to send mail")


subject="Start-Test"
mail_text="Cron-Job started"
to_addr="somewhere@example.com"
print ("Job started:")
print datetime.now()

send_mail(subject, mail_text, to_addr)
```

If I run the code from the command-line via "python " I get the following output:

```
<module 'smtplib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc'> 
Job started: 2020-01-02 14:06:31.20274

message From: myaddress@gmail.com 
To: somewhere@example.com 
Subject: Start-Test 
Cron-Job started 
a 
<smtplib.SMTP_SSL instance at 0x76bbab48> 
b 
(250, 'smtp.gmail.com at your service, [92.211.42.193]\nSIZE 35882577\n8BITMIME\nAUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8') 
Login on Server (235, '2.7.0 Accepted') 
Sending Mail {} 
Closing Connection
```

However if I run the same script from the cronjob with printing the outputs into a file I get the following:

```
<module 'smtplib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc'>
Job started:
2020-01-02 14:06:53.229564
message
From: myaddress@gmail.com
To: somewhere@example.com
Subject: Start-Test

Cron-Job started

a
failed to send mail
```

The behaviour is identical whether I have the cronjob brought in either way:
"*sudo crontab* -e" or "*crontab -e*".
In both crontabs I have the following entry (one at a time):

*@reboot python /my_script.py > /logfile.txt*

In another script I printed the PATH-variable and that is identical between the command-line and the cron-tab.

Any idea where this is going wrong? The smtplib seems to be correctly found based on the print-statement, also the python-interpreter.
Thanks a lot already in advance!

Moadl

Comment: I tried both suggestions now, the pointer to actually print the real error is well taken.
The initial error now after a startup wait-time of 60 seconds was
[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
This I "fixed" by putting in the direct IP-address which I took from a ping-response. After that I am now getting:
"[Errno 101] Network is unreachable". At that time the network is already up an running for a "long" time which I can "prove" by connecting via putty.

Comment: At reboot? You can connect with PuTTY while it's booting? Very certainly not.

Comment: @tripleee: I can connect via putty ~20 seconds after I fired off the reboot command. The sleep I had in was for 60 seconds.

Comment: There is no `sleep` in the code you posted. In any event, I definitely trust the "network unavailable" error message here.

Answer (score 0):

my answer got deleted, although i think it's still the correct answer, maybe Jean-Francois is much more wise and can post a correcting reply/comment instead of deleting mine.

So i will just repost it...

---

Probably network won't be available yet, when your script is running after reboot, so smtplib fails to connect to the SMTP server. You can add a short sleep to your cronjob, or maybe add retrying to your python script.

In order to know what exactly is going wrong, you can print your exception.

---

A `Network is unreachable` is still related to a network failure, you just ignored the DNS resolution error (`Temporary failure in name resolution`) by hardcoding the IP.

In order to double check, just run a @reboot cron with `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 > /tmp/ping_result`.

Comment: I currently cannot access the system and look at it again next week. The sleep that I put in is not in the original code above but at the moment via a shell-script that slleps for 60 seconds and then calls the python-script. My current work-around is a daily reboot at a stupid time and a scheduled start via a normal timed cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a bit of time off the system the situation is sorted.
Issue is the network unreachable and similar in the initial time after booting as @olisch suggested and the pointer from @snakecharmerb and @tripleee.

Several points for anyone else lateron reading this post and for debugging:
- output from crontab into file: 
  " > file" alone will not be enough as this will not be printing errors. 
  " > file 2>&1" will also contain error-messages
- crontab-calls to scripts require the full path in the system: When working on the scripts the usual command during testing is:
python ./my_file.py
However the cron-script will not be in that directory, hence use the full path
python /home/myname/directory/my_file.py
==> again, if 2>&1 is used in the call then a "file not found message" will be printed.